# How to control space between image and text on tkinter button widget?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I've been working on a GUI for the script I wrote for work and with a little research I've been able to create buttons with image on them for the ease of recognition. The only problem I have is that right now both the image and the text are anchored to the middle of the button which makes it clumsy with no space in between.

[image]

What I would like to do is have images aligned to the left side of a button and text to the right side. Is there any way to do it in tkinter?

Here's my UI code:

```py
def create_interface(self)->None:

    ph_plan = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.plan_image))        
    ph_bmi = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.bm_image))
    ph_calc = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.calc_image))
    ph_plot = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.plot_image))

    top = tk.Frame(self.root).grid(row=1)
    middle = tk.Frame(self.root).grid(row=2, pady=40)
    bottom = tk.Frame(self.root).grid(row=3, pady=80)


    # Create buttons
    bmi_btn = Button(top, text='Blastmaster Inputs', width=self.button_width,
                     image=ph_bmi, compound='left', bg='#f2fafc',
                     font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'), command=self.get_bm_inputs)
    plan_btn = Button(top, text='Weekly Plan', bg='#f2fafc', font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'), 
                      image=ph_plan, compound='left', width=self.button_width, 
                      command=self.get_plan_output)
    calc_btn = Button(bottom, text='Calculate sampling', height=80, width=self.button_width,
                      bg='#f2fafc', font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'), image=ph_calc,
                      compound='left', command=self.calculate_sampling)
    self.plot_btn = Button(bottom, text='Create plots', height=80, width=self.button_width,
                      bg='#f2fafc', font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'), state='disabled',
                      image=ph_plot, compound='left', command=self.create_forecast_plots)

    # Place buttons into window
    bmi_btn.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=20)
    plan_btn.grid(row=1, column=2, pady=20)
    calc_btn.grid(row=4, column=1)
    self.plot_btn.grid(row=4, column=2)  

    # Create references to image to protect from garbage collector
    self.plot_btn.image = ph_plot     
    bmi_btn.image = ph_bmi
    plan_btn.image = ph_plan
    calc_btn.image = ph_calc

    # Create labels
    label_text1 = 'Enter start date for the forecast'
    label_text2 = 'Enter end date for the forecast'        
    Label(middle, text=label_text1, font='Hevetica').grid(row=2, column=1)
    Label(middle, text=label_text2, font='Helvetica').grid(row=3, column=1)

    # Create and place data entry fields
    self.start = Entry(middle, width=38)
    self.start.grid(row=2, column=2)
    self.end = Entry(middle, width=38)
    self.end.grid(row=3, column=2)
```

Comment: You have already done that with the `compound='left'` option.

Comment: @acw1668 but `compound='left'` only makes sure image appears the the left of the text, but what I really need is space between image and text if at all possible.

Comment: Try setting `padx`, it adds space between image/text and border, and between text and image as well.  Or adding spaces at the beginning of the text.

Comment: @acw1668, omg! Adding spaces at the beginning of the text does the trick. Feeling embarrassed now that I couldn't come up with it myself haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I would like to do is have images aligned to the left side of a button and text to the right side.

Tkinter doesn't make it possible to align the image on the left edge of the button and the text on the right edge. However, you can have the text immediately to the right with some separation by simply adding one or two spaces to the text and using the `compound` option to explicitly set the image to the left of the text.

```
bmi_btn = Button(top, compound="left", text=' Blastmaster Inputs', ...)
```

Notice the space before the `B` in `' Blastmaster Inputs'`

If you want the image to the far left of the button with the text next to it, use the `justify` option:

```
button = tk.Button(..., justify="left")
```

[image: screenshot]